# Talkback prounce letter by letter instead of word by word for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, talkback

I am implementing a voice reader for EditText, the EditText is expected to input numbers.

Here is XML :

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_display"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:hint="This is Stack Overflow"
    .../>
```

when I set the Hint for example “This is Stack Overflow” in XML and once EditText is focused by talkback, it pronounces like :”T H I S I S S T A C K O V E R F L O W” letter by letter. I want it to pronounce word by word instead. How can I do that? I tried to change the inputType from “Phone” to “Text” or “textPersonName”, both don’t work